# Separating the digits of a three-digit integer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For my APCS class, my assignment was to take a three-digit number inputed by the user and to print each digit in order on separate lines. My code works fine:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class threeDigits
{
    public static void main (String [] args ){
        System.out.println("Give me a three digit integer and I will print out each individual digit");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        int digit1 = number / 100;
        int digit2 = (number % 100)/10;
        int digit3 = number % 10;
        System.out.println(digit1);
        System.out.println(digit2);
        System.out.println(digit3);
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a better, more simple way to get the same result or if this is the best way to do it. 
Even if this is the most quick-and-dirty way to get the result, I would love to see alternate ways of doing the same thing, not to hand in for a grade but just as a learning experience.

Comment: You got the idea, but implemented a solution that only works when the number has exactly 3 digits. You should now write a solution that works whatever the number of digits is, to find a more generic solution.

Comment: If you are sure that user will enter a valid 3 digit number, then instead of first converting to integer and then fetching the digits, you can just print the three characters of number string.

Comment: That seems good, because a 1 digit answer, e.g. `5`, still gets printed on 3 lines (`0`, `0`, `5`), but if number is >999, e.g. 5432, the first "digit" will be a larger number (`54`, `3`, `2`). Is that what it should do?

Comment: my teacher told us to assume the user will enter a valid 3-digit number and that we aren't required to account for any error, yet.

Comment: Does "in order" mean in order entered, or in numeric (sorted) order?

Comment: "in order " means ordered entered. if the user inputs 682, the program prints 6,8, and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate solution:

First input a integer and convert it to `String` then loop through the `String`.

```
     public static void main (String [] args ) {
        System.out.println("Give me a three digit integer and I will print out each individual digit");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        String str = Integer.toString(number);
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fails in input < 100 and prints wrong digits if input > 999

Comment: @Andreas Edited , but user only give 3 digit number.

Comment: How do you know? You didn't verify that. Users are idiots, which is why idiot-proofing code is a full-time job. And sometimes they are not idiots, just malicious, which can be worse.

Comment: Exactly, but Op says three-digit, so I do that, thanks for your advice.

Comment: to clarify, the code only has to work for a valid 3-digit but Andreas is right in saying that its imperative to "idiot-proof" code. some user could input "dog" for all we know.

Comment: @Ninja answer edited, It works for any number of digit now, I understand the point. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if Java 8 and built-in methods are allowed, is to iterate over the characters of the number as a String and print them using `forEach`.

```
int number = 12345;
String.valueOf(number).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).forEach(System.out::println);
// or String.valueOf(number).chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char) c));
```

Comment: Nice answer, but likely way out of scope of the current level of Java training. ;-)

Comment: There is no reason not to use Java 8 for someone just starting to learn the language. Ninja has already solved the task, and is asking for a better way to do it.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited with this possibility but why shouldn't `getNumericValue` be used? Is it specific to this use case or is it more general?

Comment: I misread its documentation and removed the comment. But it's not necessary. Just printing the char itself as a char is sufficient: `String.valueOf(number).chars().forEach(i -> System.out.println((char) i);`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to read the number as a String instead, and loop through the chars:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ThreeDigits
{
    public static void main (String [] args ){
        System.out.println("Give me a three digit integer and I will print out each individual digit");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number = input.next();

        for(char c : number.toCharArray())
            System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution is by using a stack.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    if(num<0)
        num*=-1;

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while (num != 0)
    {
        stack.push(num%10);
        num/=10;
    }
    int count=1;
    while(!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("digit" + count + ": " + stack.pop());
        count++;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import it.

import java.util.Stack;

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = input.nextInt();
        int iter = n, sum = 0;

        while(iter > 0) {
            sum = sum + iter;
            iter--;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + n + " is " + sum + ".");
    }
}
```